# Constrained Knapsack

Tags: algorithm

I was practising some Codechef problems and I
am stuck in this problem :

Malvika has created some n programming
contests. Each of the contests has three
problems, categorized as easy, medium and
hard on difficulty level. For the ith contest, easy
problem takes TE(i) hours and gives you PE(i)
pleasure. Similarly, medium problem takes TM(i)
hours, gives PM[i] pleasure, and a hard one has
the values TH(i), PH(i).
Today, Animesh wanted to practice some of
them. Animesh has a really bad habit of trying
problems for only a few minutes and saying to
Malvika "I am a noob, you are a pro. It's some
weird shit I don't know. Please, tell me the
solution, bro!" Having been irritated by this
behaviour numerous times in the past, she
granted him K special powers he can use before
starting the practice session. By using a single
power, Animesh can pick any two problems
irrespective of their difficulty from two different
contests and swap them.
Animesh has at max time hours before he gets
frustrated by his noobness and ends the
practice session. He wants to make the
maximum use of it by getting as much pleasure
out of this activity as possible. Animesh also
gets bored with the contest themes fairly
quickly, so he does not want to solve more than
one problem from any contest. Can you help
Animesh in estimating the maximum amount of
pleasure he can achieve out of this activity?

---

I can identify its a constrained Knapsack
problem (with weight being the time of a question and value being the pleasure of the question and capacity of the knapsack being the total time of solving questions) but cannot think of a suitable algorithm to implement the constraint.

Can anyone please help me?